# Rotate Arrow on Accordion Click

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I get this arrow rotating when the parent accordion div is clicked? Any help would be wonderful. The idea is that as you click the accordion the arrow which is an svg file should rotate, however I can't seem to get it working

HTML

```
<button class="accordion">Design <img src="./assets/img/down.svg" alt="caret-down" class="caret"></button>
        <div class="panel"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste veritatis maiores doloribus ex, culpa tenetur?</p></div>
    <button class="accordion">Development <img src="./assets/img/down.svg" alt="caret-down" class="caret"></button>
        <div class="panel"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. At rerum a voluptate nesciunt! Quam, inventore.></div>
    <button class="accordion">Search Engine Optimisation <img src="./assets/img/down.svg" alt="caret-down" class="caret"></button>
        <div class="panel"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, blanditiis. Corporis maxime eum nemo delectus.</p></div>
    <button class="accordion">Progressive Web Apps <img src="./assets/img/down.svg" alt="caret-down" class="caret"></button>
        <div class="panel"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa consequuntur obcaecati iste odit vero mollitia.</p></div>
```

CSS

```
 #services .accordion{
    font-size:1rem;
    background-color:rgba(245, 246, 250,0.4);
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:18px;
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    width:68vw;
    text-align:right;
}
#services .active, .accordion:hover{
    background-color:rgba(245, 246, 250,0.4);
    color:rgba(0, 151, 230,1.0);
}
#services .panel{
    background-color:rgba(245, 246, 250,0.4);
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align:center;
}
#services .caret{
    width:12px;
}
```

JS

```
/*accordion*/
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("caret")
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "flex") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "flex";
    }
    arrow.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(-45deg)");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently throws an error at `arrow.setAttribute`, because `arrow` is not set at this point. And `setAttribute` is not a proper way to set inline styles.

Both can be fixed easily like this:

```
this.querySelector('.caret').style.transform = "rotate(-45deg)";
```

`querySelector` returns the first element with that class it finds, and by calling it on `this`, which refers to the button, we can automatically limit it to the correct scope. And then the inline style is set using an appropriate syntax.

(`var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("caret")` can then be completely removed, you don’t need it for anything else.)

If you want the arrow to rotate back, when the element is collapsed again - then don’t place this line at the end, but in both the `if` and the `else` block. Once with `rotate(-45deg)`, and once with `rotate(0)` to set it back to normal (or whatever value you need for that state.)